# Tkinter: Calling a multithreaded instance

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, dialog

I am a beginner at python, and it is my first language. I have been tasked with something that is quickly becoming too large for me to grasp that I need to finish. I am almost done. At this moment, I have created a dialog box that serves as a Main Menu, a dialog box that is a selectable option from the main menu that runs a test, and a multithreaded instance which runs the test, opens up a "please wait" box and up on finishing the test, another dialog box pops up which declares the test complete.

My issue: Within the "Run Test" dialog, I am trying to create a button that will call the multithreaded instance into action. From the code I have parsed together with the help of others, I can not see which class to instantiate within the "Run Test" dialog box.

I am beginning to believe my implementation of threading is incorrect. However there must be a way.

This is the module I am trying to call on.

```
from slice_setup import SLICE_SETUP
import Tkinter as tk
import threading
import Queue


class GuiPart:
    def __init__(self, master, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("300x100+400+250")
        self.master.title("RSAM BCT")
        tk.Label(master, text="REDCOM SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        tk.Label(master, text="BCT - Basic Configuration Test", fg= "red").pack()
        tk.Label(master, text="Please wait...", fg= "black").pack()
        tk.Label(master, text="Estimated time: 3 min 6 sec", fg= "black").pack()

    def processIncoming(self):
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                text = self.queue.get(0)
                Complete(self.master, text)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass

class ThreadedClient:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue)
        self.running = True
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread1)
        self.thread.start()
        self.periodicCall()

    def periodicCall(self):
        self.gui.processIncoming()
        if not self.running:
            return
        self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)

    def workerThread1(self):
        obj_rcs = SLICE_SETUP()
        obj_rcs.SLICE()
        self.queue.put("Configuration Complete!")
        self.running = False

class Complete(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None, completetext=""):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.geometry("400x300+400+250")
        self.title("RSAM BCT")
        tk.Label(self, text="REDCOME SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="BCT - Basic Configuration Test", fg="red").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text=completetext, fg="dark green").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Trunk 1: Port 1: Phone 1: 760-450-4500", fg="black").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="Trunk 1: Port 2: Phone 2: 760-450-4501", fg="black").pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="    Exit    ", command=self.destroy).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    client = ThreadedClient(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and this is where I am trying to call from:

```
import sys
import Tkinter as Tk()
from bct_pleasewait import ????
import threading
import Queue
import time
sGui = Tk()

class slice_menu:

    def runtest(self):
        obj_wait = ????
        obj_wait.????

    def slicemenu(self):
        sGui.geometry("400x300+400+250")
        sGui.title("RSAM BCT")
        Label(sGui, text= "REDCOM SLICE", fg="red").pack()
        Label(sGui, text= "BCT - Basic Configuration Test", fg= "red").pack()
        Label(sGui, text= "-Ensure you are logged off of HyperTerminal", fg= "black").pack()
        Label(sGui, text= "-Turn on your REDCOM SLICE unit",
        fg= "black").pack()
        Label(sGui, text= "-Please connect your laptop to SLICE CONSOLE", fg= "black").pack()
        Label(sGui, text= "-This configuration will take 3 minutes", fg= "black").pack()
        Button(sGui, text = "     Run     ", command = self.runtest).pack()
        Button(sGui, text = "  Exit test  ", command = sGui.destroy).pack()
        sGui.mainloop()
```

This class still has minor errors in it but I just want to get this issue solved first.

Comment: I think you have to be more precise about what the problem is. Your question seems to be not motivating enough, I believe many people here could easily solve your issue if it just was a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a specific answer, but your question is very broad.

Some points to keep in mind:

- Tk is not thread-safe. That is, you should *only* invoke Tk calls from the main thread. It is OK to let other threads do non-gui work.
- In CPython, only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode, due to the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL"). So your non-gui thread could make the GUI unresponsive.

If you are only running one test at a time, and if you can divide that test into small pieces, you could use a timeout (also called [alarm handler](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)). This handler does a little bit of work, saves its state, updates the progress dialog and then exits, waiting to be invoked again.

If the test runs a long time and you want the GUI to remain responsive, I would suggest using [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of threading. Start your test in a different process, and use things like Queues and Semaphores et cetera to communicate between the GUI and non-qui processes.